# Gene knockdown vs gene knockout vs knocksideways?

Tags: molecular-genetics, gene, crispr, gene-editing

How are the techniques: Knock-sideways, knockout & knock-down different?

Answer (score 3):

Hello and welcome Adil Amchi.

In genetics and molecular biology there are differences between the terms knock-out, knock-down and (the lesser known term) knock-sideways.

[Knock-sideways](https://currentprotocols.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/0471143030.cb1520s61): Inactivates proteins. Could be done using small molecule inhibitors.

[Knock-out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gene_knockout): Gene removal, no gene expression. Could be done using CRISPR.

[Knock-down](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gene_knockdown): Gene expression is reduced. Could be done using [interference RNA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RNA_interference).

(Another reference for Knock-sideways:

> ["Importantly, the rapidity of the “knock-sideways” system allowed the researchers to observe a phenotype distinct from siRNA-mediated knockdown of the same protein..."](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1074552114002877))